# Select DF rows based on value from other DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe that looks like this,

```
starttime               code                                
2021-01-01 06:16:58.862 ON
2021-01-01 15:37:47.202 OFF
2021-01-01 15:39:48.463 ON
2021-01-01 18:27:57.523 OFF
2021-01-02 07:53:35.581 ON
```

The second dataframe looks like this,

```
starttime               value
2021-01-01 07:16:34.239 232
2021-01-01 07:16:34.439 233
2021-01-01 07:16:34.539 231
2021-01-01 07:16:34.639 232
2021-01-01 16:32:47.202 43453
2021-01-01 18:32:48.463 2321
2021-01-01 19:21:28.239 34
2021-01-02 06:51:35.232 767
```

So my goal here is to grab data from 2nd dataframe based on the value switches from ON and OFF in 1st dataframe. I need to concatenate all the data between the ON and OFF transition and store them into a new dataframe.

Is there a **pythonic/pandas** way to do it without using any for loops?

Comment: What is your expected output based on this input?

Comment: How would you link both dataframes? I am asking because starttime doesn't match in your example

Comment: @G.Anderson Expected output is something like concatenating all the values of data range between ON and OFF state in first dataframe.

Comment: @PauloMarques Start time won't match as they are an independent event of each other. I want to collect based on first dataframes start time between ON and OFF transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the dataframes vertically and then use forward-fill imputation on the `'code'` column:

```py
# concatenate dataframes vertically
df3 = pd.concat((df1, df2)).sort_index()

# use method='ffill'
df3['code'] = df3['code'].fillna(method='ffill')

df3
```

[image]

You could drop the null values as well:

```py
df.dropna()
```

[image]